# Can I download an Image from a remote system with telnet?

Tags: telnet

For example if i want to download the picture located at http://yobuddy.dude/Pictures/Motorcycles/15.jpg once i open telnet with

> o www.yobuddy.dude 80

what do i do then?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? `wget` or `curl` would work much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do a request for the individual file by typing:

`GET /Pictures/Motorcycles/15.jpg`, but, this will pull back the headers and more - you could strip the headers and save the body as a .jpg file, but, it is very awkward.

For example, this is what I see when requesting Google's logo:

[image]

(https://www.google.com/logos/classicplus.png)

The best thing you can do is use a program such as [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) which is actually designed for doing this and you could just type "curl http://yobuddy.dude/Pictures/Motorcycles/15.jpg` and it will save the picture directly without any fuss or problems.